# How can you hide "Your search yielded no results." when no keywords have been entered on the search page?

Tags: 8, search

On the core default search page located at `/search/node`, if you visit this URI the page displays "Your search yielded no results." It displays this message whether keywords have been entered that truly have no search results, as well as when no keywords have been entered. It is odd to be presenting "Your search yielded no results." to users when they have yet to actually search for anything.

What's the most appropriate way to remove this message *when no keywords have been entered*?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First find out how this string got there in the first place. Simply search your codebase for the exact string `Your search yielded no results.`. In a Vanilla Drupal you'll find only 6 occurrences of this string. 5 of them in tests, and only one in a controller, the SearchController.

Looking into the SearchController you'll see that this string is part of a render array. Keyed as `'#empty'` and themed with `'#theme' => ['item_list__search_results__' . $plugin->getPluginId(), 'item_list__search_results'],`. This means you can target that pretty easily with a preprocess function. Let's go for `item_list__search_results` since you don't know of any plugin yet.

In your theme or module implement `hook_preprocess_HOOK`. Replace `hook` with your theme or module machine name and `HOOK` with the `'#theme'` key from earlier.

Now find out if any search query has been entered at all via if `\Drupal::request()->query->has('keys')`, and for safety let's also check if there's an `'empty'` key in the `$variables` and then unset it. If you want you can tighten the condition now also on the plugin you'll find in `$variables['context']['plugin']`.

```
/**
 * Implements hook_preprocess_HOOK().
 */
function MYMODULE/MYTHEME_preprocess_item_list__search_results(&$variables) {
  // ksm($variables);
  if (!\Drupal::request()->query->has('keys') && isset($variables['empty'])) {
    unset($variables['empty']);
  }
}
```

**Hint:** Use the Devel sub-module Kint and its debugging function `ksm()` to have you any variable pretty-printed in the messages block of your site for easy debugging.

Comment: This answer is super close but contains a syntax error (missing `)` in the condition) and a logic error. It may not have been clear in my question but I'm only concerned about hiding the message when `keys` is *not* set. If `keys` exists in the query string but is empty, Drupal throws a "Please enter some keywords" message. The desired condition becomes `if (!\Drupal::request()->query->has('keys') && isset($variables['empty'])) ...`. Great answer and hints - I'll gladly accept if the above changes are made!

Comment: @komlenic – Ah yeah, that wasn't clear to me. And I also didn't experience this #empty-string on just visiting /search/node. This didn't trigger that string for me. Only when I hit the search button the #empty-string was triggered along with the `Please enter some keywords` message. Answer updated according your input.